# How to Use Rails will_paginate gem to Divide a Large Table for Print on a Single Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am making some printable tables for a client with a Ruby on Rails 3.1 app and need to repeat table headers on each page. Unfortunately, at the moment, [WebKit browsers](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826) do not support a CSS-based solution.

To solve this issue, I thought I would use the will_paginate gem.

Controller

```
def
  @books = current_library.books.order('books.title ASC')
end
```

Current View Code

```
<% @books.each do |b| %>
<table>
  <thead><th><%= b.title %></th></thead>
  <tbody>  
  <% b.chapters.each do |chap| %
      <td><%= chap.number %> ... <%= chap.name %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<% end %>
```

How do I setup the pages and step through each one? In other words, how do I get all the pages of the pagination on one view page?

Alternatively, is there a better approach I should pursue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using `Enumerable#each_slice` here. It allows you to split a large enumerable object into a series of smaller slices, and then iterate on those slices. It's quite nice for this sort of thing, doesn't require any extra math in your loops, and doesn't require a gem.

Here's an example for a collection with 10 items on a page:

```
<% @books.each_slice(10) do |slice| %>
  <h1>Header Information</h1>
  <h2>Awesome</h2>

  <% slice.each do |book| %>
    <table>
      <thead><tr><th><%= book.title %></th></tr></thead>
      <tbody>  
      <% book.chapters.each do |chap| %
          <tr><td><%= chap.number %> ... <%= chap.name %></td></tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  <% end %>

  <p>Some footer information</p>
<% end %>
```

This approach will only work if you assume that each book record takes about the same amount of space (so you don't end up with oversized or undersized pages), but that would be a problem with will_paginate as well.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know `.each_slice` existed until now. The problem I don't know how to get around is that when I do `.each_slice` the object, that removes the activerecord association. To clarify, I am hoping to have n (e.g., 10) chapter/rows in each table so I would actually want something like `<% book.chapters.each_slice do |chap| %>`

Comment: If that's the case, you may just have to increment a counter and check with modulo every row. There might be a more elegant solution, but if there is I don't know of it.

Comment: Thanks XanderStrike. I used the modulo approach and it works fine but,  pretty, it is not.